# Cannot commit over an applied mq patch

Tags: java, version-control, mercurial, commit

I added (hg add) 1 new file and made some other changes.
Tried to commit and push all.
Result

```
Cannot commit over an applied mq patch
```

hg status shows

```
A exchange.rates\exchange.rates\src\main\java\com\company\exchange\rates\utilities\CsvService.java
```

How "Cannot commit over an applied mq patch" can be fixed?

Comment: When is shows this status? Any code causing this status?

Comment: @ArseniProkharchyk, post updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't "be fixed". Because inability of creating changeset on top of applied MQ-patch is good and expected behavior, not bug, for Mercurial.

With dirty working dir on of of patch you can only

- refresh current patch with dir-changes

or

- create new patch for MQ on top of applied with dir-changes

Comment: Thank you! How "refresh current patch with dir-changes
or
create new patch for MQ on top of applied with dir-changes" can be done?

Comment: @ArthurDn - https://kbmangk.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/some-tips-on-mercurial-patch-queues-mq/ - with CAUTION, due to date